# overriding delete with parameters

Tags: c++

I can override global `operator new` with different parameters, so for example I can have:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
void* operator new (std::size_t size, int num) throw (std::bad_alloc);
```

which can be called separately as

```
int* p1 = new int; // calls new(size_t)
int* p2 = new(5) int; // calls new(size_t, int)
```

since each of these can potentially use some different allocation scheme, I would need a separate `delete()` function for each. However, `delete(void*)` cannot be overloaded in the same way! `delete(void*)` is the only valid signature. So how can the above case be handled?

P.S. I am not suggesting this is a good idea. This kind of thing happened to me and so I discovered this "flaw" (at least in my opinion) in c++. If the language allows the `new` overrides, it *must* allow the `delete` overrides, or it becomes useless. And so I was wondering if there is a way around this, not if this a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep track of the different memory regions you allocate with your different `new` overloads, you can tag them with the version of `new` that was called.

Then at `delete` time you can look the address up to find which `new` was called, and do something different in each case.

This way you can guarantee that the correct logic is automatically associated with each different `new` overload.

As pointed out by baruch in the comments below, there is a performance overhead associated with the maintenance of the data you use for tracking, and this logic will also only work as long as the overloaded delete is not passed anything allocated using the default delete.

As far as tracking overhead, it seems to me that the minimum overhead method of tracking the type of the allocation is to allocate the amount requested, plus a small amount of additional space at the start of the allocated region in which to tag the request type (sized according to conservative alignment requirements). You can then look at this tag region on delete to determine which logic to follow.

Comment: This is only a partial workaround. What if I only have the second `new` overload in my example, leaving the plain default `new` in place. So one version of new uses my custom allocation, the other is the default. In the overloaded `delete`, how can I call the default `delete` if it is not memory allocated by me? This is besides the large overhead such a lookup would incur.

Comment: @baruch. You're right: deleting anything that comes in allocated by default new would be a problem. However the large overhead on the lookup seems somewhat moot - after all, the standard library/OS has to do something similar on each delete.

Comment: The standard library needs to do no such thing since it has only one type of allocation/deallocation scheme, and the pointer is being passed in to the `delete`.

Comment: Good question, I have the same question: you can make destructors with parameters, so how do I handle the parameters of the destructor with the calling of delete operator?

Comment: It seems to me that the minimum overhead method of tracking the type of the allocation is to allocate the amount requested, plus a small amount of additional space at the start of the allocated region in which to tag the request type (sized according to conservative alignment requirements). You can then look at this tag region on delete to determine which logic to follow. Is this really substantially more costly (in time, obviously it is costly in space if you're allocating many small objects) than the standard library logic for memory allocation/deallocation?

Comment: @AlexWilson I hadn't thought of the over-allocating idea.

Comment: @Bentoy13 You *can't* have parameters to destructors.

Answer (score 8):

> I can override global operator new with different parameters

Those are called *placement allocation functions*.

> delete(void*) is the only valid signature.

No.

First, some terminology: A *delete expression* such as `delete p` is not just a function call, it invokes the destructor then calls a *deallocation function*, which is some overload of `operator delete` that is chosen by overload resolution.

You *can* override `operator delete` with signatures to match your placement allocation function, *but* that overload will only be used if the constructor called by the placement new expression throws an exception e.g.

```
struct E {
    E() { throw 1; }
};

void* operator new(std::size_t n, int) throw(std::bad_alloc) { return new char[n]; }
void operator delete(void* p, int)  { std::puts("hello!"); delete[] (char*)p; }

int main()
{
    try {
        new (1) E;
    } catch (...) {
        puts("caught");
    }
}
```

The *placement deallocation function* which matches the form of placement new expression used (in this case it has an `int` parameter) is found by overload resolution and called to deallocate the storage.

So you can provide "placement delete" functions, you just can't call them explicitly.  It's up to you to remember how you allocated an object and ensure you use the corresponding deallocation.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a placement delete which matches the placement operator new. *And you can't call it directly*. This is because the placement delete is only used to deallocate memory when the constructor of the new'ed object throws.

```
void *operator new(size_t, Area&); // placement new
void operator delete(void*, Area&); // matching placement delete
...
Area &area;
SomeType *t=new(area) SomeType(); 
// when SomeType() throws then `delete(t,area)` from above is called

// but you can't do this: 
delete (area) t;
```

A common way to overcome this, is to use write an overloaded "destroy" function, which accepts all kinds of parameters.

```
template<class T> void destroy(Area &a, T* &pt) //<-you can't do this with 'delete'
{
 if (pt) { 
    pt->~T();        // run the destructor
    a.freeMem(pt);   // deallocate the object
    pt=NULL; // nulls the pointer on the caller side.
 }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. This is not *placement* new. This is *allocating* new (or whatever it is called).

Comment: @baruch: It *is* placement new. See iso14882:2011 section 5.3.4.11

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: Do not do this. All forms of non-placement `new` are redundant in C++11 and horrifically unsafe, for example, return raw pointer. If you want to allocate objects in a custom place, then use a class with an `allocate` function if stateful or a free function if not. The best treatment for `new` and indeed, `delete`, is to excise them from your program with prejudice, with the possible exception of `placement new`.

Edit: The *reason* why it's useless for you is because you're trying to use it for a purpose which it was not intended for. All you can use the extra params for is stuff like logging or other behaviour control. You can't really change the fundamental semantics of `new` and `delete`. If you need stateful allocation, you *must* use a class.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. Ideally, perhaps simply not doing it is the best solution, but that may not be an option. The OP specifically said he knows this isn't a great idea, but he needs a solution regardless.

Comment: I think you were unclear, are you really suggestion to never use `new` except placement new? How should you allocate memory?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Through `make_shared`, `make_unique`, and such.

Comment: And as the implementor of `make_shared` what am I meant to use?  Since there is no `std::make_unique` someone must write it for you, how should they allocate memory?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The lack of `std::make_unique` is a defect, and admittedly, you may have to use `new` and `delete` to work around that defect, for now. However, if you are the implementer of the Standard library, then there are many rules which do not apply to you- this being just one example, identifier restrictions being another. The point is, using `new` and `delete` without a protective wrapper is a very silly idea anyway.

Comment: (N.B. you only need `new` to write `make_unique` not delete :-)  What about authors of custom (but non-standard) allocators? I think your statement is far too strong ("redundant" and "horrifically unsafe") and so much less helpful than it could be if worded reasonably

Answer (score -1):

You're wrong. It [is possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax#Placement_delete) to provide a placement delete.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. This is not placement new. This is allocating new (or whatever it is called).

Comment: @baruch, it _is_ placement new. The default `operator new(size_t, void*)` called by `new ((void*)p)` doesn't allocate anything, but other forms of `new (x)` can, and they're all "placement new".